# ExtJS 3 Combobox connected with Ext.data.JsonStore doesn't open at second++ click

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, store

I've trouble with my Combobox. I've build a simple combobox which is configured with a JsonStore to provide remote data. The combobox opens at the first click without problems, the JSON data is requested and Ext shows me the full dropdown list.

But sporadly at the second (sometimes third) click, the combobox neither open nor load any remote data.

Here's my config:

```
    var config = {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [{
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'count',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'created_at',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'updated_at',
            type: 'int'
        }],
        root: 'result',
        idProperty: 'id',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/myHandler/loadDropDownList'
        })
    };
```

The combobox itself is loaded in a toolbar:

```
    var config = {
        height: 27,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            text: 'Your preference?:',
            // @todo inline style -> CSS
            style: {
                'font-weight': 'bold',
                'color': '#15428B',
                'font-family': 'tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif',
                'font-size': '11px'
            }
        }, 
        '->',
        // align the following items on the right side of the toolbar
        {
            xtype: 'combo',
            itemId: 'table-combobox',
            store: new myStore(),
            valueField: 'name',
            displayField: 'name',
            value: ' - Please Choose - '
        }]
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The combobox may be running into trouble querying the database everytime you select it. If you don't need the combobox data to be updated throughout a user's session (i.e. the dropdown values don't change in between the times the user clicks the combobox), you can add this config to the combobox:

```
mode:'local',
```

(ExtJS4: `queryMode:'local'`)

It will take the data that the *remote* store has autoLoaded and will not requery the database store every time it is dropped down.

Comment: Hm, okay that sounds good. I'll try it - Thank you for your response!

Comment: @silentCoder if that works out for you dont forget to check off the answer (check mark on the left side here)

Comment: Hm, sorry that didn't work for me. See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-mode -> If you do not want the store to be automatically loaded the first time the trigger is clicked, set to **'local' and manually load the store**. For that I must manually load the store but I don't want to that in my application :-(