# Ext.form ComboBox doesn't populate unless clicked first

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

What I have is one dropdown that fetches a list of IDs, whose selection determines which list should be fetched for the second dropdown. The problem is that unless I click the (empty) second dropdown *first*, it won't populate after a choice is selected in the first dropdown. *However*, once this "workaround" is performed, the second dropdown always populates properly any time a choice is selected in the first dropdown, which is the intended functionality (other than the initial weirdness).

Sorry if that's confusing, here's my code:

```
var restaurantInput =
  {
      createInput: function(parentObject, inputClassName, value, propertyObject)
      {
          var restaurantList = [];
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://mysite.com/restaurants/",
              success: function(response)
              {
                  var results = (typeof response === 'string' ) ? JSON.parse(response) : response;
                  for (i in results.restaurants){
                      restaurantList.push({restaurantID: results.restaurants[i].restaurant_id.toString(), restaurantname: results.restaurants[i].name});
                  }
              }
          }).done(function(){
              var restaurantCombo = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.ComboBox",
              {
                  store:
                  {
                    filterOnLoad: false,
                    sortOnLoad: false,
                    fields: ["restaurantID", "restaurantname"],
                    data: restaurantList
                  },
                  name: "restaurantName",
                  id: "restaurantName",
                  displayField: "restaurantname",
                  valueField: "restaurantID",
                  listeners: {
                      'select':function(){
                          updateMenuList(Ext.getCmp("restaurantName").getValue());
                      }
                  }
              });
              var str = '<div id="restaurantComboDiv"></div>';
              parentObject.html(str);
              restaurantCombo.setValue(value);
              restaurantCombo.render("restaurantComboDiv");
          });
      }
  };
```

---

```
var menuCombo = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.ComboBox",
  {
      store:
      {
        filterOnLoad: false,
        sortOnLoad: false,
        fields: ["menuID", "menuname"],
        data: []
      },
      name: "menuName",
      id: "menuName",
      displayField: "menuname",
      valueField: "menuID",
      multiSelect: true
  });

var menuInput =
  {
      createInput: function(parentObject, inputClassName, value, propertyObject)
      {
      var str = '<div id="menuComboDiv"></div>';
      parentObject.html(str);
      menuCombo.setValue(value);
      menuCombo.render("menuComboDiv");
      }
  };
```

---

```
function updateMenuList(RID)
  {
      var menuList = [];
      $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://mysite.com/restaurants/"+RID,
              success: function(response)
              {
                  var results = (typeof response === 'string' ) ? JSON.parse(response) : response;
                  var i=0, len=0;
                  for (i=0, len=results.menu.length; i<len; i++)
                  {
                    menuList.push({menuID: results.menu[i].menu_id, menuname: results.menu[i].name});
                  }
              }
          }).done(function(){
              menuCombo.setValue("");
              menuCombo.store.removeAll();
              menuCombo.store.add(menuList);
              menuCombo.bindStore(menuCombo.store);
          });
  }
```

When the page first loads, the user can select from a list of Restaurants. When a choice is made, an event is fired which should update the Menu's store. The user then tries to select their order but the Menu is blank. If the user chooses another Restaurant, the Menu is populated properly. Every other time the user chooses any Restaurant, the Menu continues to populate.

If the user's first choice is to open the Menu, it is obviously blank, as a Restaurant has yet to be chosen. If the user then chooses a Restaurant, the Menu populates properly.

I've tried to work around this by calling `menuCombo.expand();` in the update function's `.done()` and it somewhat works. This causes the Menu to expand immediately after a Restaurant is chosen, and the proper items are all there. However, once the Menu collapses for any reason, it will be blank when expanded again, which is the exact same problem as before.

Comment: updateSeriesList vs. updateMenuList? //your code looks ugly.

Comment: Oops, didn't replace that one. It's all 'series' in my working code, I renamed it to 'menu' here to help explain the intended use. The update function does get called successfully every time.

Comment: Any ideas why this would happen? Or it works fine for you? Or just how to clean up what I've got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem (had exactly same issue as you), set queryMode to local...

comboBox.queryMode = 'local';

(reference: [ExtJS 3 Combobox connected with Ext.data.JsonStore doesn't open at second++ click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853417/extjs-3-combobox-connected-with-ext-data-jsonstore-doesnt-open-at-second-clic))

Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounded like the opposite problem (my combo box opens at second++ click, but not the first) but it fixed my issue. Thanks for linking this!